# ipyparallel view.sync_import does not bind to additional name

Tags: python, ipython-parallel

i have the following issue with ipyparallel (using python 3.4). The `view.sync_imports` does neglect the extra module name to which i try to bind them with the 'as' directive.

**Example:**

```
c = Client(profile='slurm')
v = c[:]
with v.sync_imports():

    import pandas as pd

Output: importing pandas on engine(s)
```

So pandas is only available under the name 'pandas'.
Anyone a suggestion what i can do about this?

I also tried the %px magic, does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
import pandas as pd
```

Python interprets that as two operations: `import` and `assignment`

```
import pandas
pd = pandas
```

`sync_imports()` is implemented as an [import hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks), which (as far as I can tell) only has access to the import part, and not the assignment part. That means that `sync_imports` can only support `import pandas` and not `import pandas as pd`.

However, `%px` *should* work, as it is just executed directly:

```
import pandas as pd     # local
%px import pandas as pd # remote
```

Or as a cell magic with `--local`, if you want to do shared initialization of all engines and the local workspace:

```
%%px --local
import pandas as pd
def defined_everywhere():
    """..."""
```